# New to Golang and for some reason nested if else is not working

Tags: if-statement, go, struct, interface

The inner if else is not being reached although its correct. I don't know why its not matching the equality test for strings as a result of which the call to functions using interface variable is not working

```
fmt.Println("Enter a valid query:")
fmt.Printf(">")
reader:=bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
inp,_:=reader.ReadString('\n')
query:=strings.Split(inp," ")           
fmt.Println("0 : ",query[0])
fmt.Println("1 : ",query[1])

st:=query[1]
if query[0]=="cow"{
fmt.Println("inside cow going to",st)
    var a animal=cow{"Cow"}
    if query[1]=="eat"{
        a.eat()
    } else if query[1]=="move"{
        a.move()
    } else if st=="speak"{
        fmt.Println("inside cow speak")//Not reaching here even
        a.speak()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do let me know if additional context is needed for the code.

Comment: Just `fmt.Printf("%q %q\n", query[0], query[1]) ` and you'll _see_.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a `\n` (line feed) in your `query[1]`
if you use `query:=strings.Fields(inp)` instead of `query:=strings.Split(inp," ")`  your problem should go away.